# macbook pro making repetitive clicking noise

Tags: macbook-pro

My macbook pro has started making a repetitive clicking noise every 4 seconds. It kind of sounds like a woodpecker or something, not a scraping noise.. does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: I would check your hard disk and make sure it has a backup

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, it's either the hard drive,but it sounds to me like something might be impeding one of your fans. I used to hear something similar with an older MBP I had and it was the fan on the GPU. Might be worth taking it into a qualified Apple dealer/service point.